# GWT deferred binding not working after compilation

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to implement deferred binding using generators. When I an testing deferred binding in dev mode it works as expected, when I am switching to production deferred binding is not working for some reason.
I have following classes

```
public class GeneratorTest implements EntryPoint {

    //should be modified by generator
    public static class GeneratorTestPrefs extends PreferencesImpl {
...
    }
...
}

public class PreferencesImpl implements Preferences {
...
}

public interface Preferences {

    public void load(String key, Storage storage);

    public void store(String key, Storage storage);
}
```

And following definition in gwt module.xml

```
<generate-with class="com.xxx.xxx.gwt.generator.server.PreferencesGenerator">
    <when-type-assignable class="com.xxx.xxx.gwt.generator.client.Preferences"/>
</generate-with>
```

I added log for classes created by

```
GeneratorTestPrefs prefs = GWT.create(GeneratorTestPrefs.class)
```

In case of dev mode, in log file, I see GWT **is using** class created by generator (**GeneratorTestPrefs_PreferencesAdapter**)

```
[java] INFO: deferred binding: com.xxx.xxx.gwt.generator.client.GeneratorTestPrefs_PreferencesAdapter
```

In case of production mode, in log file, I see GWT **is not using** class created by generator (**GeneratorTest$GeneratorTestPrefs**)

```
Wed Apr 01 15:48:06 GMT+300 2015 com.xxx.xxx.gwt.generator.client.GeneratorTest INFO: deferred binding: com.xxx.xxx.gwt.generator.client.GeneratorTest$GeneratorTestPrefs
```

I have no idea what is wrong. Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It was invalid implementation in generator. It returned null when class was generated already and because of it the proper version were used on some permutations only

```
public String generate(TreeLogger logger, .....) ...{
    String className = null;
    if (printWriter != null) {
        SourceWriter writer = composer.createSourceWriter(ctx, printWriter);
        ....
        className = composer.getCreatedClassName();
    }
    return className;
}
```

when I changed

```
    String className = packageName + "." + simpleName;
```

It started to work as expected.